# Excel VBA - Use string variable as input to Union Method

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Somewhere in the Sheet called Sheet 2 I have the following:
[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUw0I.png)

It uses the TEXTJOIN function to concatenate the values in Column A. The string in B100 is variable S (see the code).

I'm attempting to use this as the input to a method in my macro.
The following is a code snippet from the Module:

```
Dim ListofSheets, WorkingSheet As Worksheet 
Dim C0, C1 As Range   
Dim S As String
Dim WholeRange As Range

Set ListofSheets = Sheets("Sheet2")
...

Set C0 = WorkingSheet.Range(PanelColumn & StartingRow & ":" & PanelColumn & lRow)
Set C1 = WorkingSheet.Range(LoadCaseColumn & StartingRow & ":" & LoadCaseColumn & lRow)

S = ListofSheets.Cells(100, 2).Value

Set WholeRange = Union(S)
    WholeRange.Copy

End Sub
```

C0 and C1 is calculated in the code and are the following ranges:

```
C0= C7:C310
C1= D7:D310
```

When the above code is run, an error is produced on the line `Set WholeRange = Union(S)` with "Compile error: Type Mismatch"

I have tried `Set WholeRange = Union(C0, C1)` which works successfully, but I do not want to use this as there is actually more variables that can be chosen.

My question is why can the string be passed as a parameter, and how can I rectify the problem?

N.B: I have more than 2 ranges in the code which is not shown here. The script decides which ranges to use. Since more than 2 ranges need to be inputted, I am using the `Union` method instead of the `Range` method

Comment: Doesn't Union require a range? Is `S` a string? What happens if you use `Union(INDIRECT(S))`?

Comment: @Yorik, `INDIRECT` is a worksheet function.  I think you meant to use `RANGE(S)`.

Comment: @ReyJuna I forgot to add this to the question, but I have multiple ranges (4+) being calculated. The two above were just examples.So using Range will not work since I have more than 2 input parameters. My original question has been edited.

Comment: You are using `S`, a string, to represent the names of variables.  `UNION` requires at least two range arguments.

Comment: The output of the above shows that the value of `S` is `C0,C1` - two arguments. Problem is, it thinks it is only one argument.

Comment: It is only one argument.  `UNION` requires ranges and even if `S="A1:B1"` then `UNION(S)` will error because there is only one range within the `()`.

Comment: If you don't know how many ranges in advance, you could loop and do a `UNION` for each new range, such as `SET WholeRange = UNION(WholeRange,<new_range>)`

Comment: I meant to say "if `S="A1:B1"` then `UNION(RANGE(S))`" in my comment above.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand. I just need to make the code think that the string "C0,C1" contains the variables that I already defined,

Answer (score 0):

So `S` is a string and even though it reads as if it is specifying a Range, `Union()` requires a Range *object*, which is why you are getting a type mismatch error. You are passing the wrong type.

So as long as the value of `S` specifies a proper range, try something like:

```
Dim UnionRange as Range 'declare at top
...
Set UnionRange= WorkingSheet.Range(S) 'insert this after S is assigned
...
Set WholeRange = Union(UnionRange) 'change the range assignment to this
```